# Keep track of state of GameObject after destroying it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state, gameobject

I have a `ScriptableObject` called `WeaponInfo` that keeps track of different information about weapons that doesn't change (magazine max, rate of fire, degradable bool, etc.) and this class also has a reference to a base weapon Prefab that inherits from `Monobehaivior`. This prefab is what is instantiated and then given a reference to the `WeaponInfo` scriptable object. My problem with this setup is as follows:

I want the weapon to have a durability value that decreases with each use. I can't put this in the `ScriptableObject` since `ScriptableObject`s data is "static", and changing it is not a good idea. I also can't put it inside the `GameObject` Prefab itself, because every time the player unequips then reequips the weapon, the durability value is reset to its default state.

I looked around the internet for solutions, but no one has a similar example to my setup where the weapon is  unequipped by deleting it from the scene. I also want the ability to store this weapon in a chest. Originally I was gonna do this by storing a reference to the `ScriptableObject`, but I won't be able to save the durability.

What is the best approach to solving this issue? If anyone wants, I can share code, but I wanted to keep the post simple since my issue is conceptual more than it is syntax.

EDIT: Here is the code for my WeaponInfo class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Weapon Item", menuName = "Inventory/Weapon Item")]
public class WeaponItem : Item
{
    [Header("Game Object Info")]
    public GameObject WeaponPrefab;
    public Vector3 DefaultRotation;
    public Vector3 DefaultScale;
    [SerializeField]
    public BulletItem Bullet;

    [Header("Weapon Info")]
    public bool Automatic;

    [SerializeField]
    public int Magazine_Max;

    [SerializeField]
    public int Ammo_Max;

    [SerializeField]
    public int Reloading_Time;

    [SerializeField]
    public float ROF;

    public bool degradable;

    public override void Use()
    {
        base.Use();
        
        //oldWeapon is of type WeaponItem
        var oldWeapon = WeaponSwapper.Instance.SwapWeapon(this);
 
        Inventory.Instance.AddItem(oldWeapon);
        Inventory.Instance.RemoveItem(this);
    }

}
```

And here's the code attached to my weapon prefab:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AmmoWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.NonSerialized]
    public WeaponItem WeaponInfo;

    private Inventory inventory;

    protected float reloadingTimer;
    protected bool reloading;

    [SerializeField]
    public int Magazine_Current;

    [SerializeField]
    public int Ammo_Current;

    public int durability;

    private float elapsedTime = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        inventory = Inventory.Instance;

        inventory.OnInventoryChangedCallback += UpdateAmmo;

        reloadingTimer = 0;
        reloading = false;

        LoadAmmo();
    }

    //this method loads a clip into the magazine
    private void LoadAmmo()
    {
        var totalAmmo = inventory.GetCount(WeaponInfo.Bullet);

        if(totalAmmo >= WeaponInfo.Magazine_Max)
        {
            Magazine_Current = WeaponInfo.Magazine_Max;
            Ammo_Current = totalAmmo - WeaponInfo.Magazine_Max;
        } else
        {
            Magazine_Current = totalAmmo;
            Ammo_Current = 0;
        }
    }

    //callback for whenever ammo is added to the inventory.. also used to reflect the ammo in the UI
    private void UpdateAmmo()
    {
        var totalAmmo = inventory.GetCount(WeaponInfo.Bullet);

        Ammo_Current = totalAmmo;

        if (Ammo_Current <= Magazine_Current)
        {
            Magazine_Current = Ammo_Current;
            Ammo_Current = 0;
        }
        else
            Ammo_Current -= Magazine_Current;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Automatic
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && WeaponInfo.Automatic)
        {
            Fire();
        }

        //Manual
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !WeaponInfo.Automatic)
        {
            Fire();
        }

        //Set reloading flag after a certain amount of time passes
        if (reloading)
        {
            reloadingTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (reloadingTimer > WeaponInfo.Reloading_Time)
            {
                reloadingTimer = 0;
                reloading = false;
            }
        }

        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        Mathf.Clamp(elapsedTime, 0, WeaponInfo.ROF);
    }

    protected void Reload()
    {
        if (reloading)
            return;

        reloading = true;
        reloadingTimer = 0;

        LoadAmmo();
    }

    protected void Fire()
    {
        if (Magazine_Current == 0)
            Reload();

        if (!CanFire())
            return;

        var target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        var bulletPrefab =
            Instantiate(WeaponInfo.Bullet.BulletPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        var bulletScript = bulletPrefab.GetComponent<Bullet>();

        var spriteRenderer = bulletPrefab.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRenderer.sprite = WeaponInfo.Bullet.Sprite;

        bulletScript.BulletInfo = WeaponInfo.Bullet;

        bulletScript.SetDirection(target - transform.position);

        elapsedTime = 0;

        Magazine_Current--;
        inventory.RemoveItem(WeaponInfo.Bullet);

        //ISSUE IS HERE. durability is reset to initial value whenever this gameobject is initialized again
        if (WeaponInfo.degradable)
        {
            durability--;
            if (durability == 0)
            {
                MessageHandler.Instance.DisplayMessage(WeaponInfo.ItemName + " degraded completely.");
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    protected bool CanFire()
    {
        if (reloading || elapsedTime < WeaponInfo.ROF || Magazine_Current == 0 || !inventory.Contains(WeaponInfo.Bullet))
            return false;

        return true;
    }


}
```

And finally, here's the snippet where the weapon is instantiated and attached to my weapon rod:

```
public WeaponItem SwapWeapon(WeaponItem NewWeapon)
    {
        DestroyAllChildren();
        var previousWeapon = CurrentWeapon;
        CurrentWeapon = NewWeapon;

        InstantiateAndAttachWeapon(CurrentWeapon);

        return previousWeapon;
    }

    private void InstantiateAndAttachWeapon(WeaponItem weapon)
    {
        WeaponPrefab = Instantiate(weapon.WeaponPrefab);

        var weaponScript = WeaponPrefab.GetComponent<AmmoWeapon>();

        weaponScript.WeaponInfo = weapon;

        var sprite = WeaponPrefab.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        sprite.sprite = weapon.Sprite;

        Debug.Log(CurrentWeapon.DefaultRotation);

        WeaponPrefab.transform.parent = transform;

        WeaponPrefab.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(
            CurrentWeapon.DefaultRotation);

        WeaponPrefab.transform.localScale = weapon.DefaultScale;

        WeaponPrefab.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

        SetAmmoScript(weaponScript);
    }
```

Comment: You may want to share your code for help with this one. The structure of your classes will dictate how you can actually do this, There are a lot of ways to do what you are talking about though. It could be as simple as instantiating a new instance of some sort of `CurrentWeaponStats` that tracks the information that changed, and then `CurrentWeaponStats` should have ways to access the static information as well. Then you would have the GameObject use those stats, which you could save or inject into a different game object when you do decide to destroy the current one.

Comment: I added the code to my post. When you say save, you mean serialize it somehow as maybe a json or a text file?

Comment: What I could do is not allow the player to own 2 copies of the same WeaponInfo, and therefore I can keep a dictionary of WeaponInfo to int(durability) in the GameManager that keeps track of each weeapon's durability. It's a concession I'm willing to make in order to make things simpler, but I'm surprised something this primitive doesn't have a simpler solution.

Comment: Perhaps it's in your `WeaponSwapper`, I'm wondering why you needed to call `WeaponPrefab = Instantiate(weapon.WeaponPrefab);` instead of just assigning it as `WeaponPrefab = weapon.WeaponPrefab;`. Isn't the `weapon.WeaponPrefab` already instantiated? It's hard to tell what your `Instantiate` method is doing.

Comment: No, weapon.WeaponPrefab is a reference to the prefab asset, and is being instantiated when I equip the weapon. Sorry, the code can be a little messy some places

Comment: Is `durability` always 0? Or is default being defined somewhere else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244238/discussion-between-ibrennan208-and-majd-odeh).

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to keep the weapon instance alive?  You could hide it, then you don't need to hack together a solution for saving the state.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I agree, this seems more like the class structure of the solution could be better approached.

Comment: I've made a project and uploaded it to github in attempts to give you an idea of what to do. I'm not sure how much of what you are doing is enforced by Unity, but my example should hopefully provide insight regarding inheriting base classes and keeping instances alive while referencing a specific one at a time. here is the link: https://github.com/brennani/WeaponExample